# Wysiwyg images not moved to public cache

Tags: orocommerce

I started with the WYSIWYG integration for writing blog posts. All loads fine (styles, properties, content), but the url generated to load the image/file points to a directory/file that does not exist. The uploaded file/image does exists in the var/cache and is shown on my edit page inside the WYSIWYG editor.

When I try to access the generated url I get redirected to the /profile page with following notice:

> The map cannot be displayed. Please try again later or contact your administrator.

Am I missing something?

I've looked inside the CMSBundle and tried to make my code as similar as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the "File applications" WYSIWYG field option has "commerce" in the list.

[image]