# orocommerce wysiwyg editor - file / image wrong src

Tags: wysiwyg, orocommerce

I have similar issue that [Wysiwyg images not moved to public cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697153/wysiwyg-images-not-moved-to-public-cache)

when I add a file or image in wysiwyg, it displays properly in editor but after saving, it doesn't display in admin nor front.
Generated markup src is incorrect/not properly replaced:

```
<picture id="irozi"><source srcset="{{ wysiwyg_image('22','d9ffaffc-f286-4707-bd4b-29504628acc2','wysiwyg_original','webp') }}" type="image/webp"><img src="{{ wysiwyg_image('22','0872c470-f50a-4290-8043-96ffd5e205d2','wysiwyg_original','') }}" id="icysf" alt="test picture"></picture>  
<a href="{{ wysiwyg_file('21','43acd9a6-4b54-4439-9d1d-08241dd5a63e') }}" title="test file" target="_self" class="digital-asset-file no-hash">my-file.csv</a>
```

My field already exists (in a custom bundle) and "File applications" doesn't show in "Entity Management".
Do I need that conf? How to achieve it with a migration?

What else should I do to have a correct src for files and images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File applications config is required if you want to display an image that is ACL protected within the application. You can set it using a migration, e.g.:

```
$queries->addQuery(
            new UpdateEntityConfigFieldValueQuery(
                'Acme\Demobundle\Entity\FancyFile',
                'image',
                'attachment',
                'file_applications',
                ['default', 'commerce']
            )
        );
```

The issue might also be related to image processing. Please, check the log file for errors.

**UPDATE**

Also, as a WYSIWYG field has some twig placeholders it has to be rendered with the applied postprocessing.

On the storefront it should be rendered with:

```
{% if entity.contentStyle|length -%}
    {%- apply spaceless -%}
        <style type="text/css">{{ entity.contentStyle|render_content }}</style>
    {%- endapply -%}
{%- endif %}

{{ entity.content|render_content }}
```

There are also ready-to-use layout block types: `wysiwyg_style` and `text_with_placeholders`.

On the back-office there is a macro

```
{% import '@OroEntityConfig/macros.html.twig' as entityConfig %}
{{ entityConfig.renderWysiwygContentPreview(entity.content)|raw }}
```

Where the `entity.content` is the field path to render.

The team will update the documentation to mention that.

Comment: hi! thanks for the migration but it still doesn't work

the problem is the src after save (admin listing or in front-end):

request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET https://[...]/view/%7B%7B%20wysiwyg_image('22','0872c470-f50a-4290-8043-96ffd5e205d2','wysiwyg_original','')%20%7D%7D"
wich is obviosly wrong

Comment: We've found a miss in the documentation. I updated the answer.

Comment: I updated rendering but I don't know if it's better or worse: now image src or file href are empty ><

I'm using Oro 5.4.4 if it matters

Comment: OK I finally found the reason why it didn't work: I missconfigured the field ><
btw thanks for the renderer cause I would had missed it anyway :)